# How to get a specific column out of parent row in a qtreeview

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview

As the title states I am trying to pull a value out of a specific column in the parent row of the currently selected row in a qtreeview.

I have tried doing it this way:

```
index = self.view.currentIndex()
parent_index = index.parent()
parent_col1_index = self.model.index(parent_index.row(), 1)
text = self.model.data(parent_col1_index)
```

On a data structure like this, with id3 selected:

```
- id1                    id1
    - id1.id2            id2
        - id1.id2.id3    id3
```

When I pull data from the model using the parent_index variable I get whatever column I clicked on from the parent row (id2). But when I try to get a specific column from that parent with the parent_col1_index variable I get the correct column but from the top row (id1). This is consistent even with a bigger data set, If I try to get a column from the parent row of any row that is 2 deep I get the 1st row of the treeview returned.

I assume it has something to do with how I am created the column specific index with model.index. But I am not sure how else this can be done.

Any ideas?

If it helps at all here is a working example. When you click the pushbutton it should output id2 if you have id3 row selected

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from collections import deque

test_data = [
    {"column2": "id1", "column1": "id1", "column3": "id1-value", "lvl": 0},
    {"column2": "id2", "column1": "id1.id2", "column3": "id2-value", "lvl": 1},
    {"column2": "id3", "column1": "id1.id2.id3", "column3": "id3-value", "lvl": 2},
]

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.eventTree = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.eventTree.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 621, 391))
        self.eventTree.setObjectName("eventTree")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 89, 25))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 10, 391, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Column1", "Column2", "Column3"])
        self.eventTree.header().setDefaultSectionSize(180)
        self.eventTree.setModel(self.model)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clickHandle)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.importData(test_data)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))

    def clickHandle(self):
        index = self.eventTree.currentIndex()
        parent_index = index.parent()
        parent_index = self.model.index(parent_index.row(), 1)
        text = parent_index.data()
        self.label.setText(text)

    def importData(self, data, root=None, extend=False):
        self.model.setRowCount(0)
        if root is None:
            root = self.model.invisibleRootItem()

        seen = {}
        values = deque(data)
        while values:
            value = values.popleft()
            if value['lvl'] == 0:
                parent = root
            else:
                pid = ".".join(value['column1'].split(".")[:-1])
                if pid not in seen:
                    values.append(value)
                    continue
                parent = seen[pid]
            dbid = value['column1']
            parent.appendRow([
                QtGui.QStandardItem(value['column1']),
                QtGui.QStandardItem(value['column2']),
                QtGui.QStandardItem(value['column3']),
            ])
            seen[dbid] = parent.child(parent.rowCount() - 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, figured it out. It was simply that I shouldn't be calling the model.index method to create the index for the specific column in the parent. What I needed there was to call the index.sibling method. Like so:

```
parent = index.parent()
parent_col1_index = parent.sibling(parent.row(), 1)
```